# Как записать данные в переменную юзера Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я создал дополнительную переменную(строку) в профиле юзера по этому мануалу: https://gist.github.com/withoutwax/46a05861aa4750384df971b641170407

В этой строке я храню информацию о пользователе. 
Достучатся к ней могу так: `current_user.information`

Но как мне сделать метод, который берет одну строку и сохраняет ее в конец стоки `information`?

Пока что так, но это не работает (результат отображается, но не записывается в переменную юзера) :

```
current_user.information << id
```

Через редактирование профиля все сохраняется.

Comment: скорей всего, Вы забыли вызвать save у юзера после добавления информации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно так:

```
current_user.update(information: current_user.information + id)
```

Вот только почему выбран такой странный способ хранения, как строка? Почему не json?

Comment: Мне нужно хранить в переменной id любимых фотографий юзера. Я решил так будет проще, чем создавать еще одну таблицу с несколькими полями. Но теперь сомневаюсь в своем выборе. Спасибо за помощь, буду думать.

Comment: Так точно будет не проще. Для фотографий у вас ведь есть уже таблица? Что мешает просто добавить связь `has_many :favorite_photos, class_name: 'Photo'` и наслаждаться всеми встроенными плюшками? :)

Comment: И да, если мой ответ решает поставленный вами вопрос, не сочтите за трудность, примите его